# how to format the table in ssrs according to the group?

Tags: formatting, grouping, reporting-services

[This is my link for the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jt3rs.png)

i m new to ssrs and i simply no nothin about it. i have grouped my main satus and substatus. as you can see in the table i get 3 rows in customer id, count and created date as per rowws in substatus. i just want a single row for them. and in count also i want single row not repeating in three rows the same count.for the count expression i have given the value of substatus to count with the scope of main status. please tell me how can achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are many customers, each with a main status and a sub-status? And you want to see how many customers there are with each substatus? If so, you need to:

- Group on main status and sub status (as you have done)
- In the header/footer of the sub status group you need to count on the customer id
- The detail section of the report can then include any information you want to see about individual customers within those groups (e.g. Customer ID, Created Date) or can be hidden entirely.

If you try to show customer information in the sub-status or main status group, it will show only you aggregate information (e.g. count, sum etc). In this instance it looks like the default of first(fields.customer id.value) has been added to the substatus group header/footer.

Comment: ok now i have to prepare a chart. and on x-axis i have created date. and on y axis the contract count. i want contract count for distinct date. but my date on x-axis is repeating. why is it so?

Comment: I suggest asking a new question, since this is an unrelated topic to the original question (even though it's using the same data).